# Windows 10: How do you create a PhoneLine class?

Tags: c#, windows-phone

I would like to programatically make a call with my windows phone 10, however I have no idea how to create a PhoneLine class can someone point me how to do it?

I am both new to C# and the mobile world.

I found the API reference here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.calls.phoneline

and what I attempted to do is:

```
new Windows.ApplicationModel.Calls.PhoneLine();
```

However what I get is:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
    Error   CS1069  The type name 'PhoneLine' could not be found in the 
namespace 'Windows.ApplicationModel.Calls'. This type has been forwarded to 
assembly 'Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract, Version=3.0.0.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null, ContentType=WindowsRuntime' Consider 
adding a reference to that assembly.    App2    C:\documents\visual studio 
2015\Projects\Helloworld2\App2\MainPage.xaml.cs 33  Active
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read the error carefully you can see that it says this:

> *"This type has been forwarded to 
>   assembly 'Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract, 
>   Version=3.0.0.0, 
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null, ContentType=WindowsRuntime' **Consider 
>   adding a reference to that assembly.**"*

You need to add a reference to the `Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract` assembly, as the class you are looking for has been moved over there instead.

According to [this blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/lucian/2015/10/23/how-to-call-uwp-apis-from-a-desktop-vbc-app/) it can be found here:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract\1.0.0.0\Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract.winmd
```

Remove `(x86)` from the path if you're on a 32-bit system.

Comment: What do I need to install to get that assembly?

Comment: @Har : Nothing, I think. You should be able to find it in the window that pops up when you are to add a new reference to your project.

Comment: @Har : You found them? If not, read the beginning of the `Out of date: first steps` section in this blog: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/lucian/2015/10/23/how-to-call-uwp-apis-from-a-desktop-vbc-app/

Comment: yes they were under the "Windows Mobile Extensions for the UWP"

Answer (score 5):

As the error says ,

> This type has been forwarded to assembly
>   '**Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract**, Version=3.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null, ContentType=WindowsRuntime'
>   **Consider adding a reference to that assembly**

You need to add `Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract` dll to the project as reference

[image]